# Inequality - dominating, bounding number

Tags: set-theory

I am stuck with one inequality from Cichon Diagram: $\mathfrak{b} \leq \mathfrak{d}$. Maybe it is easy, but I have no idea how to proof it.

where: 
$\mathfrak{b} : = \mathfrak{b}(\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}, \leq^{*}) = \min \left\{ \left| F \right| : F \subseteq \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \wedge \ \forall_{g \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}} \ \exists_{f \in F} \ \exists_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{\infty} \ g(n) < f(n) \right\}, \\
\mathfrak{d} : = \mathfrak{d}(\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}, \leq^{*}) = \min \left\{ \left| F \right| : F \subseteq \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \wedge \ \forall_{g \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}} \ \exists_{f \in F} \ \forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{\infty} \ g(n) < f(n) \right\}.$

$\exists ^{\infty }n\in {\mathbb {N} }$ means: "there are infinitely many natural numbers n such that...", and $\forall ^{\infty }n\in {\mathbb {N} }$ " means "for all except finitely many natural numbers n we have...".

Could you please help me or give me some hint?

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by $\exists^{\infty}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\forall^{\infty}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$? "There exist infinite many $n \in \mathbb{N}$" and "for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$"?

Answer (score 1):

Given sets $X$ and $Y$ of cardinal numbers, if $X \subseteq Y$ then $\mathrm{min}(Y) \le \mathrm{min}(X)$, and so it suffices to prove that 
$$\left\{ \left| F \right| : F \subseteq \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \wedge \ \forall_{g \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}} \ \exists_{f \in F} \ \forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{\infty} \ g(n) < f(n) \right\} \subseteq \left\{ \left| F \right| : F \subseteq \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \wedge \ \forall_{g \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}} \ \exists_{f \in F} \ \exists_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{\infty} \ g(n) < f(n) \right\}$$
The proof of this fact comes down to the fact that if a formula $\varphi(n)$ is true of all but finitely many natural numbers $n$, then it true of infinite many natural numbers $n$.